# Changing language of database content in Joomla

Tags: database, joomla, localization

I have a database with a lot of information and I display it on my site. Now I need to translate this info into other languages. I have thought of using joomfish but to my knowledge joomfish is only for articles. Is there an easy way to do this on Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

Try the link below for the extensions. Also give a try to Mambelfish.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/translations-for-joomla